# search an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array, of which I'm trying to perform a search for a particular element:

```
grid ({"row": row, "col": col})
```

Can anyone provide advice on how to locate an element in this array? I've tried something like this, but I can't seem to figure out if I'm doing it correctly.

```
grid.indexOf([row, col])
```

Any advice would be great.

Comment: The first code line - that's not an array ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your array you are keeping objects, so comparing them only by value does not work in JS.

You can do it the old fasion way (iterate):

```
function indexOfCell(row, col){
  for(var i=0; i< grid.length;i++){
     if(grid[i].row === row && grid[i].col === col){ // this code can get complex, when working with many properties
       return i;
     }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Second solution would be filter from Array prototype:

```
function filterByRowAndCol(element) {
  if (element.row === row && element.col === col) {
    return element;
  } else {
    invalidEntries++;
  }
}

var arrByRowAndCol = grid.filter(filterByID);
```

Source: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I assume that grid is an array of objects with row and col properties.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an array, it's an object.

For an array you could just use:

```
array.forEach(function(element, index, array) {});
```

Since this is an object however you need to do a little more work:

```
Object.keys(grid).forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  if(element === some_random_name) {
    // Do whatever you need to here.
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually, for searching through an array, [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) would be a better fit. The first one is widely supported (IE9 and upwards).

Comment: for searching the object i would use: for (var element in grid) {
  if (element === 'search_name') {}
}

Comment: @BrendanMullins—that requires a *hasOwnProperty* test, *Object.keys* is a better approach.

Comment: @RobG well.. no you dont. this for loops through all properties and if none match it wont execute the code inside the if.. so to test it again is redundant
*edit: try it: http://jsfiddle.net/orttb64g/1/

Comment: @BrendanMullins—for..in iterates over all enumerable properties on the object and its `[[Prototype]]` chain, so you might match an inherited property rather than an own property. *Object.keys* avoids that. It may not be required for an *ad hoc* solution, but it is for a general case.

Answer (score 0):

This is an object, to access the element in your object you can use like this

```
grid = {"row": 10, "col": 12 };
alert( grid.row ); //will alert 10
alert( grid.col ); //will alert 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You're working with an object, not an array.

You'll also need to refine your syntax for the object to work with it correctly. Try this: `var grid = {'row': 'row', 'col': 'col'};`

Then, you can loop through your object properties to find what you need:

```
var findValue = function (someKey) {
    for (var property in grid) {
        if (grid.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (property === someKey) {
                return grid.property // return the value
            }
        }
    }
};
```